# Generate both beans and META-INF in the same folder jaxb2-maven-plugin 2.3

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, maven-jaxb2-plugin

I'm using `jaxb2-maven-plugin` version 2.3 to generate jaxb java beans.

- It works well and generate the beans as expected under `src/main/java/x/y/z`.
- A `META-INF/sun-jaxb.episode` file is created under `src/main/java`.

The point is that I want to be able to generate both the beans and the `META-INF/` folder inside the same directory, such as **src/main/java/x/y/z**. Otherwise at least not generating the `META-INF/` folder under `src/main/java`.
Is that possible ? If I don't set a `<packageName>` then a default package (defined in .xsd file) is applied to the generated beans.
Here is my current configuration in `pom.xml` file :

```xml
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
             <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
             <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
             <version>2.3</version>
             <executions>
                 <execution>
                 <id>schema-x</id>
                 <goals>
                     <goal>xjc</goal>
                 </goals>
                 <configuration>
                     <xjbSources>
                         <xjbSource>src/main/resources/path/to/file.xjb</xjbSource>
                     </xjbSources>
                     <sources>
                         <source>src/main/resources/path/to/file.xsd</source>
                     </sources>
                     <packageName>x.y.z</packageName>
                     <outputDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/java</outputDirectory>
                     <clearOutputDir>false</clearOutputDir>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: I think you should reconsider the output directory. The `src/main/java` is intended for files you want to commit/push to your source control management system (e.g. git). All generated sources end up by default under `target/generated-sources/`, they are not committed and will be generated with every build. That will bring you closer to the intended solution.

Comment: Remove the configuration for `<outputDirectory>${basedir}/src..` let the plugin decide what's correct. apart from that never change the contents of files/directories which are under version control via build process...as @RobertScholte mentioned..

Comment: Not sure if I understand everything. If I remove <outputDirectory> then jaxb beans are only generated under target, so I can't use them in my Java services...

Comment: Yes you can, the maven-compiler-plugin is aware of it: it can handle multiple source directories, all compiled classes end up in `target/classes`

Answer (score 1):

This applies to jaxb2-maven-plugin but also to any plugin that generates java sources : you should genetate the output in the build directory.

If not and generating in `src` folder like here, you'll then have to commit / push generated files and have a non stable build.

The [documentation](https://www.mojohaus.org/jaxb2-maven-plugin/Documentation/v2.4/xjc-mojo.html#outputDirectory) of the plugin says about `outputDirectory` :

> Corresponding XJC parameter: d.
>
> The working directory where the generated Java source files are created.
>
> Type: java.io.File
> Required: Yes
> Default: ${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/jaxb

The maven compiler and the IDE is then capable to get this directory (or any subdirectory in generated-sources by convention) and you'll be able to use generated source code in your own code